# How to execute a task only once in Prefect?

Tags: python-3.x, etl, prefect

I have a flow in Prefect, where the the starting and the stopping of the DB client is happening for each mapped task.
Below is a visual of the end of an example ETL.

The `save_transformed_data_to_db` takes an `unmapped(database)`, `unmapped(db_client)` and a mapped `data` values.

Is there a way to set a task to run only once at beginning and once at end of the full flow and if yes - how?

[image]

Comment: The starting and stopping of the DB client should not be occurring for each task based on your DAG, unless each mapped task in running in a different process and your client is somehow reinstantiating when it is pickled / unpickled.  In that case, this PR is intended to address this pattern: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/pull/3139